# Unable to append redirected output files in windows

Tags: windows, perl, file, append, truncate

I am using a log file which is logged in using redirected output method and not the usual logging functions or subroutines.

I need to open the file in appending mode in order to truncate the same every hour.
In linux, i can successfully open the file in append mode and use truncate() function.
But in windows, the file doesnt open in append mode or open using the perl file operators.
Running with if statement gives me false value condition on appending the files, in windows.

the same code and logic works differently on linux and windows.
tried the >>,+>,> file operators in perl but none works in windows.

What can be the reason for the same and solution for this?

Comment: If open returns false, `$!` and `$^E` contain relevant error messages.  What are they?

Answer (score 1):

No reason appending to a file wouldn't work in Windows. But this nugget in [`perlport`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlport.pod#truncate) might be what you need to know:

**truncate**

> If a `FILEHANDLE` is supplied, it must be writable and opened in append mode (i.e., use `open(FH, '>>filename')` or `sysopen(FH,...,O_APPEND|O_RDWR)`. If a filename is supplied, it should not be held open elsewhere. (Win32)